# I need to delete all empty cells liens in openpyxl module python but its give me error

Tags: python, excel

I need to delete all empty cells line by that don’t have value in it by this code from openpyxl module python

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# set some values in cells A1 to D4 and E6
ws['A1'] = 'Hello'
ws['B1'] = ','
ws['C1'] = 'world'
ws['D1'] = '!'
ws['E6'] = 'Goodbye'

min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = ws.calculate_dimension().split(':')

min_col = ord(min_col) - 64
max_col = ord(max_col) - 64

for row in reversed(range(1, int(max_row) + 1)):
    if all(cell.value is None for cell in ws[row]):
        ws.delete_rows(row)

for col in reversed(range(1, int(max_col) + 1)):
    if all(cell.value is None for cell in ws[f"{col}:{col}"]):
        ws.delete_cols(col)

wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

But its give me this error:

```
error in line 15 
min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = ws.calculate_dimension().split(':') 
: not enough value to unpack (excepted 4 , got 2)
```

I tried  many ways to solve it but still give me same error, how i can slove it or another code that can delete empty cell lines

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting only once, at `:` - that's not enough: you have to further seperate the column information (letters) from the row information (digits) for each part of the split. You could use [`CellRange`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.html?highlight=rows#openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.CellRange) to do the whole thing instead:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# set some values in cells A1 to D4 and E6
ws['A1'] = 'Hello'
ws['B1'] = ','
ws['C1'] = 'world'
ws['D1'] = '!'
ws['E6'] = 'Goodbye'

min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = CellRange(ws.calculate_dimension()).bounds
print(min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row)
```

results in

```
1 1 5 6
```